# Copying rows from one database file to another

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have 2 separate sql databases, they both have the same field but are not attached and are completely separate files. One of the database files has a few hundred rows of data and I want to copy a few of those rows into the other database file. Some people have said to use sql statements to copy the data but the databases are not linked in any way so I am not sure as to how these statements would work. Is there no software where I can just select the correct rows and copy them over, or create a new database with the ones selected?

I hope this makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Is it **mysql** or **sqlite**? What you're asking is totally vendor specific.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the database platform you are using, there should be commands/tools that will allow you to perform bulk data imports and exports from/to a file (e.g. a CSV file).  Try exporting the rows you wish to copy from the database on the first server into an intermediate file, copying that file to the second server, and then importing it into that database.